# "Phantom" touches on capacitive buttons on new refrigerator LCD panel every ten minutes

Tags: electrical, appliances

The timing is random and varies from 10 minutes to 2 hours between "phantom touches" on the touch buttons on refrigerator panel.
The touches activate the functions, like turning on the dispenser light or trying to set an alarm.
We had a similar thing happen previously with an electric cooker with a touch panel - but it stopped when we didn't run an exercise machine on the same circuit - but we've gotten rid of the exercise machine and the "phantom" touches are now happening on the refrigerator.
Do we have a serious problem here?
Thanks!

Comment: If you consider this behavior a serious problem, it's a serious problem. Call the manufacturer and demand it be fixed; this is covered by the warranty.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the grounding on the receptacle the refrigerator is plugged into.

Comment: Thanks Dan, Can I ask how the grounding might be related?
Do you think that there might be voltage surges or drain through the ground wire?

Comment: What other things are on the refrigerator's circuit?

Comment: Is there a Stack Exchange site that would cover poltergeists?

Comment: I've tried it on all of the circuits in the property and the same effect occurred.

Comment: I just checked ground with multimeter and it shows full voltage, so I'm assuming that it is functioning correctly.

Comment: It's new, it does not work correctly, ask the manufacturer to fix it. Also: why I like my appliances dumb - much fewer things to go wrong if the fridge just concentrates on keeping things cold, rather than needing firmware updates...

Comment: Just because you are reading full voltage from the hot to the ground doesn't mean it is wired correctly. If it was wired with a false ground I would fully expect it to start doing this. Also check if it is the only thing on it's breaker, if it shares a breaker, that could cause problems too.

Comment: I'm inclined to doubt a false ground, since it's one of a hundred apartments in a building.
There have been some water intrusions to electrical circuits on the property due to flooding though.

Comment: Can you post a wiring diagram for your fridge? This sounds like RFI, not poltergeists, but a wiring diagram would help us put together a plan of attack.

Comment: I just wanted to post the apparent solution to this problem: We noticed that there was a faint buzzing sound coming from the circuit breaker box in the apartment.

The buzzing got louder and the fridge started having phantom button inputs when we jiggled one of the plug in circuit breakers which we had used in place of the old ceramic circuit breakers.

When we put the old ceramic circuit breaker back in the buzzing stopped, and the fridge has been fine since.

Does this mean that we've solved the problem, or could it indicate a serious issue with our circuit breaker panel?

Answer (score 1):

You live in a large complex. This just made the probability that someone else in the facility has a fridge or some other device that is cycling every 10 minutes to 2 hours causing spikes on the line and your phantom problems. You might try a [surge arrest outlet](http://www.homedepot.com/p/CE-TECH-1-Gang-Duplex-Surge-Protector-Outlet-5580/204294364) and see if this helps. A cheap plug in one may be a better first try.

Comment: I just wanted to post the apparent solution to this problem: We noticed that there was a faint buzzing sound coming from the circuit breaker box in the apartment.

The buzzing got louder and the fridge started having phantom button inputs when we jiggled one of the plug in circuit breakers which we had used in place of the old ceramic circuit breakers.

When we put the old ceramic circuit breaker back in the buzzing stopped, and the fridge has been fine since.

Does this mean that we've solved the problem, or could it indicate a serious issue with our circuit breaker panel?

Comment: Sounds like that breaker was arcing. This happens after the breaker trips under load an arc causes some damage to the hammers after many times there are pits and not a good contact. Sometimes flipping the breaker on & off 10 times will clear the problem. Everything needs to be turned off on the circuit for safety from the repeated trips. I would be concerned because you stated you tried all the outlets are they all on the same breaker?

Comment: We tried it on different circuits and it had the same problem.

Comment: Maybe the arcing breaker on one circuit was causing enough voltage fluctuations throughout all of the circuits in the apartment to mess with the capacity touch buttons on the fridge?
It was definitely arcing when we wiggled the plug in breaker. Since we've replaced it with the original ceramic breaker there seems to be a better contact and there's been no problems and no "phantom touches" on the fridge touchpad.
Would we be safe to assume that the problem is all fixed now? Nothing to worry about? Thanks

Comment: Look at my earlier comment any appliance on the same leg could have caused this. Your statement was all outlets were checked now edited and gone.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post the apparent solution to this problem:
We noticed that there was a faint buzzing sound coming from the circuit breaker box in the apartment.

The buzzing got louder and the fridge started having phantom button inputs when we jiggled one of the [plug in circuit breakers](https://2ecffd01e1ab3e9383f0-07db7b9624bbdf022e3b5395236d5cf8.ssl.cf4.rackcdn.com/Product-800x800/2a6b2f46-26f4-4af3-93c4-fffddb293f5d.jpg) which we had used in place of the old ceramic circuit breakers.

When we put the old ceramic circuit breaker back in the buzzing stopped, and the fridge has been fine since.

Does this mean that we've solved the problem, or could it indicate a serious issue with our circuit breaker panel?

Comment: It sounds like that breaker is defective...

Comment: Do you mean the newer plug-in breaker?

Comment: We tried a couple of them and the same thing happened. It just seems like the old ceramic breaker makes a better contact ... and we haven't had the problem since we put back the ceramic breaker.
Does it sound like we can safely leave it now?

Comment: What is this "old ceramic breaker" you're talking about?

Comment: The one that was there before.
Looks like this: 
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eSOPIXXQ5_w/hqdefault.jpg